# Click button to Edit Table titles

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with Column title. There is also a edit button. If I click the button, Table title should be a Input field with title name as a value in it. Edit button will turn into Save Button.

I can rename the title and Save the new names. I not good in jquery and what I made creating bunch of input fields and I can't save new names. **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/has9L9Lh/51/)**

Any help will save my day. Thanks in advance.

**jQuery:**

```
var textInfo = $('.table th').text();

$("html").on('click', '.btn-danger', function() {
   $('.table th').append('<input id="attribute" type="text" class="form-control" value="' + textInfo + '" >');

    $('.btn-danger').text('Save');
}) ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fiddle that solves your problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/has9L9Lh/54/

It uses a common approach of toggling an element's class (or some other attribute), to determine the state of your program. In this case, it determines whether or not the columns are in edit-mode, and changes the `button` text and `th` html accordingly.

```
$("html").on('click', '.btn-danger', function() {

       var editMode = $(this).hasClass('edit-mode'),
           columns  = $('.table th');

    if (!editMode){

        $(this).html('Save').addClass('edit-mode');

        columns.each(function(){

            var txt = $(this).text();
            var input = $('<input type="text">');
            input.val(txt);
            $(this).html(input);

        });

    } else {

        $(this).html('Edit').removeClass('edit-mode');

        columns.each(function(){

            var newName = $(this).find('input').eq(0).val();
            $(this).html(newName);

        });

    }

}) ;
```

Comment: That's really great ! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

• you should not use id in the append this will create multiple id of the same name. 
• use `$(".form-control").length` to check if it exist. this will solve multiple input when button is clicked multiple times. 
• create a new button to submit your change.
• create another click event for the new button. 
• than use it `$.val()` to get input value than pass that value to the new table title.  and you are done.

I hope this will point you to the right direction. :D