# How to set value to an input filed from other text and update the text based on user input

Tags: jquery

I have a scenario where some title can be seen initially. There is an "Edit" button. If user click on that button, that text will be converted into a input filed. The value should be that title. When user type anything and click the "Update" button, that title should be changed according to the user input text. For example,

There is a title "User" and an "Edit" button. When, user click on the "Edit" button, the scenario will be changed like this: `<input type="text" value="User">`. And that "Edit" button will be changed to "Update" button. When user type anything (i.e: Person) and click on the "Update" button, input filed will be gone and "Update" will changed to "Edit" again. so, there will be then title "Person" and the "Edit" button. I have tried to make it. But, as I am not good at jQuery, I can't make it perfectly. Please, help me to make the functionality correctly. [Here is my fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/vuqvtz3f/2/)

I think, if I can fix this line, my functionality will be correct:

```
$('.title-input').val($(this).parent().find('.title').text());
```

****************Update********************************

[I can see a very similar question is posted at some minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627040/click-button-to-edit-table-titles/27627295#27627295). At that solution, each title can be taken for setting the initial value of input like this way:

```
columns.each(function(){

            var txt = $(this).text();
            var input = $('<input type="text">');
            input.val(txt);
            $(this).html(input);

        });
```

But, mine is not related with table. So, how can I correct this line for setting the initial value of input filed?

```
$('.title-input').val($(this).parent().find('.title').text());
```

Comment: You already asked this question, but it seems like you're basically there. Just clear out the value of the input so they stop concatenating every time you click edit.

Comment: No, I didn't ask this question at previous!

Comment: But, after clicking the "Edit" button once, all titles is set as value of an input filed. How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69hf0gva/4/).

A couple things.

```
$("body").on('click', '.update', function() { 
    $('.title-input').keyup(function() {
     // ...
```

First off, you're creating a new event handler for `.title-input` every time the Update button is clicked.  This is going to call the keyup function like billions of times after multiple "updates", but you only want it to be called once.  You need to move it out of the event delegate.

Secondly, you need to think about what `$('.title-input').val($(this).parent().find('.title').text());` is doing.  What does `this` refer to in this scope?  The Edit button - and its parent is `body`.  So you're finding all elements with the title class in `body` and concatenating all of them together, and setting this value to each of the titles.

To fix this (and I hardcoded it) I gave each `title` div its own unique ID, so that line targets specific title, one at a time.

```
$('#user').val($('#user').parent().find('.title').text());
```

Comment: Fist-of-all, fiddle is not correct. all title is set with "t" initially. Second-of-all, for some reason, I can't apply individual id to each title. So, I've to do it without id :(

Comment: Then what's your rationale for writing `<input value="t">`?  I've updated the fiddle and changed it to `<input value="User">`, etc. It should work as intended, given the behavior you wanted, and it answers the question that you asked in the title.  Also, this answer should provide you with enough context about the problem (that you are improperly using `$(this).parent()`) to answer your question.